# How to filter range and copy to bottom of table in different sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to filter & select all columns (A to R) which contain the value "New" in column R. I then want to copy this selection and paste as value it to the bottom of the table on worksheet "Worklist".

I don't understand why the code is using an "If" function to look at the subtotal and think I did the copy & pasting part wrong, since I'm getting an error.

```vb
Sub CopyPartOfFilteredRange()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ProcessingSheet")
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("A1:R" & lastRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="New"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then 'count visible cells in column "A" other than the header
                .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destinations:=Sheets("Worklist").Cells(.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
            End If
    
        End With
     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Should be `Destination` not `Destinations` and you probably want to qualify the target range `Destination:=Sheets("Worklist").Cells(Sheets("Worklist").Range("B"...`

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Filtered Data feat. Subtotal

- [`Range.Subtotal method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.subtotal)
- `SpeacialCells` will raise an error if no matching values are found by the `AutoFilter`. `Subtotal` is used to avoid this by returning the number of found values.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPartOfFilteredRange()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ProcessingSheet")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("A1:R" & lastRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="New"
            If WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
                Dim dws As Worksheet
                Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worklist")
                .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1) _
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                    Destination:=dws.Cells(dws.Range("B" & dws.Rows.Count) _
                    .End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
     End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code and let me know how you go.  It works (tested) based on your description of the data.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPartOfFilteredRange()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LRow As Long, PasteRow As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ProcessingSheet")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worklist")

LRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp).Row
PasteRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Set rng = ws1.Range("A1:R" & LRow)

With rng
    .AutoFilter 18, "New"
    .Offset(1).Copy ws2.Cells(PasteRow, 2)
    .AutoFilter
End With

End Sub
```